# Google chrome is displaying all text as solid boxes

Tags: google-chrome

So I changed the case on my pc recently because the old one was a bit beaten up and now Google chrome displays unreadable text but only on the actual pages stuff like tab names and the links on the bookmark bar are all fine

The pc in question is running win 10

Other browsers work fine this problem is only on chrome I have provided a picture for reference

[this is what the text looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA4oV.jpg)

Comment: Did you connect everything up properly? Is there a connection missed?  Is there a ground missing?

Comment: Everything is plugged in correctly